# Android Hide keayboard on Done button click inside a webview in actvity

Tags: android, webview, keydown

I have an Activity with a webview inside.

When I click inside a text input in the html page displayed, the keyboard shows.
There is a real time search/filter when typing inside the text input.

Then I wand to hide the keyboard, when the done button or arrow is tapped.

I've tryed to add :

```
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {..}
```

or

```
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {..}
```

But none of those function works.
How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to override onKey and try something like this:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
  //todo
}

return false;  }
```

Dont forgett to implement View.OnKeyListener

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work : 

    mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    //todo
                }
 return false;  }
 });

Comment: So there is a problem with your site in webview i think..you should check this too..

Comment: I tried with google.com in my webview an when I type text, I have the text inside the search field but i have no event in my activity